# Select the next non empty field in hive

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive, impala

I have a table with 6 fields that looks like this:

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field6
ABC    45     XYZ           JKL    BNM
       65            QWE    JKL    
WER           YUI    IOP    GHJ
```

I want to pull the data from that table above to a new table with 5 fields where we ignore the empty values. My final table should look like this:

```
Result1 Result2 Result3 Result4 Result5
ABC     45      XYZ     JKL     BNM
65      QWE     JKL
WER     YUI     IOP     GHJ
```

I have started to write a massive conditional query with CASE WHEN but it's getting out of hand and prone to errors.
Is it possible to get that table using a regex_extract query in Hive?

Comment: I don't know Hive SQL (or Hive), but I might question your design if you end up in this situation in the first place.  How did you arrive at such sparse data?

Comment: If you drop empty column data from select statement of the query , there is high chance that you corrupt the data. Like  in the example you gave JKL is value of column Field5 in Inut data however in output you need JKL to value of Result4 Column.

Comment: By "empty values" do you mean empty strings or NULLs?

Comment: Empty strings - where field = ""

Comment: The data will need to fit another layout later. If it were up to me I'd just concat everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assuming "empty values" are Nulls**

```
select  fields[0]   as Field1
       ,fields[1]   as Field2
       ,fields[2]   as Field3
       ,fields[3]   as Field4
       ,fields[4]   as Field5

from   (select  split(concat_ws(string(unhex(1)),*),'\\x01') as fields
        from    mytable
        ) t
```

---

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ABC    | 45     | XYZ    | JKL    | BNM    |
| 65     | QWE    | JKL    | (null) | (null) |
| WER    | YUI    | IOP    | GHJ    | (null) |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

---

Simplified version, assuming comma (`,`) does not appear in your fields:

```
select  ...

from   (select  split(concat_ws(',',*),',') as fields
        from    mytable
        ) t
```

**Assuming "empty values" are empty strings**

```
select  fields[0]   as Field1
       ,fields[1]   as Field2
       ,fields[2]   as Field3
       ,fields[3]   as Field4
       ,fields[4]   as Field5

from   (select  split(regexp_replace(concat_ws(string(unhex(1)),*),'^\\x01+|\\x01+$|(\\x01)+','$1'),'\\x01') as fields
        from    mytable
        ) t
```

---

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ABC    | 45     | XYZ    | JKL    | BNM    |
| 65     | QWE    | JKL    | (null) | (null) |
| WER    | YUI    | IOP    | GHJ    | (null) |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

---

Simplified version, assuming comma (`,`) does not appear in your fields:

```
select  ...

from   (select  split(regexp_replace(concat_ws(',',*),'^,+|,+$|(,)+','$1'),',') as fields
        from    mytable
        ) t
```